# Minimum and maximun number of mixin right now?

Tags: monerod, ringct, ring-signatures, ringsize

Is it a hard rule that there needs to be 11 ring signatures right now for a transaction to take place right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ring-size is now fixed at 11. So, 10 decoys (mixins) and 1 real.